# How to get Dataset table to generate the insert statment .(sql ce3.5 and Dataset with visual studio 2010 express )

Tags: insert, tableadapter

I was able to generate update statments excep the insert statement  for the file query for a dataset for ce 3.5 database table on a c# visual studio 2010 express project with  sql ce 3.5.

However I got run time error:
Update requires a valid InsertCommand when passed DataRow collection with new rows
from

```
  myTblAdaptor.Update(myTbl)
```

I did make the fill method generate all update stements and direct db....  But I just can't seem to find the myTblAdaptor.Insert. Actually the wizard results did not list Insert statement. don't know why. the sql was SELECT [category], [Value], [seq] FROM [favorite]

so I tried to create one by adding an insertquery to myTbl on the dataset design surface.  that generated Insert1 method.

Then I tried add the InsertMethod by

right click on the dataset surface, selected view code,

Then at the end of the file I added the:

```
namespace myappNS.myDSTableAdapters
{
public partial class myTblAdapter
{
    public int Insert(string category, string value, int? seq)
    {
        return Insert1(category, value, seq);
    }
}
}
```

I also tried to see if I can manually Define InsertCommand to the adaptor but could not find such.

what can I do?

thx in advance for any help.

Comment: I also tried myTblAdapter.Adapter.InsertCommnad = new SqlCeCommand( 
    "insert into myTbl values(@category,@Value,@seq)",
    favoriteAdapter);
However i got "rewarded" with exception for
    "The number of columns in the query and the table must match. [ Number of columns in query = 3, Number of columns in table = 4 ]"
 on the myTblAdapter.Update(myTbl);

Answer (score 0):

my mistake, I shoudl have lcued in on the primary query not generating Insert Statment or numbers of columns not matched. that would simply mean the datbase table definition differes form teh dataset's definition or primary query!

so to fix the error delete the table from the dataqset and then drag drop the database table form DataExporer onto the dataset design surface